# Backbone.js - Marionette ItemView onDestroy() never called

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Im having a strange problem where the onDestroy() method of my ItemView never seems to run.
I'm using Marionette v 2.2.1. Here's a very simplified version of what I've got.

```
myItemView.js
-------------

initialize: function() {
  console.log('ItemView init');
  var self = this;
  this.listenTo(eventsModel, 'change', function(){
    console.log('changed, lets do something');
    self.doSomething();
  });
  this.listenTo(eventsModel, 'destroy', function(){
    console.log('lets destroy ourselves');
    self.destroy();
  });
}

onDestroy: function() {
  console.log('hurray, destroyed!');
  this.stopListening();
}

doSomething: function() {
  console.log('doing something');
}


myController.js
---------------
var myView = new myItemView({model: aModel})
eventsModel.trigger('change');
eventsModel.trigger('destroy');

output:
//ItemView init
//changed, lets do something
//doing something
//lets destroy ourselves
```

As you can see onDestroy() never fires... what am I missing?

Comment: It is the same issue. Also views implement the onClose method. Haven't tested this, but I bet that this method also fires when you call region.close(); Afaik, you don't need to trigger an explicit destroy event via the model.

Comment: The destroy trigger actually represents a "close" button in the app. We have an event manager keeping track of all trigger-able events with Radio. Essentially, when the user closes it, I want to destroy everything. The regions don't seem to have a close method. I'm fairly new to backbone, but it seems like I'm in garbage collection hell. I'm not really understanding what I should/shouldn't, can/can't call destroy on... or is it close...?

Comment: Just for the heck of it can you add a `onBeforeDestroy` callback? Btw, events handled with `this.listenTo` are unbound automatically when the view is destroyed, see https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#view-destroy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes regions do have a close method:

[image]

Closing a view should be as simple as just closing the region, which I usually do from the controller.

I don't know if this may be helpful to you, but the way I do this, is to set up the controller as follows:

```
var Ctr_Test = Marionette.Controller.extend({ 

    initialize: function(options){ 
        this.region = new Marionette.Region({ el: "#some-region"}); 
        this.events(); 
    }, 

    events: function(){ 
        //Trigger any event you'd like from the view to call close(); 
        Zwoop.on("app:reset", _.bind(function(){
            this.close(); 
        }, this)); 
    }, 

    showTest: function(){ 
        this._showTest(); 
    }, 

    _showTest: function(){ 
        //Render some views in the region 
        var itemview = new Itemview(); 
        this.region.show(itemview); 

    }, 

    //Unbind all events 
    onClose: function(){ 
        Zwoop.off("app:reset"); 
        this.region.close(); 
    }

});
```

One attention point is to always clean up all the events that you bind in the controller, otherwise this will result in memory leaks. If you use listenTo in the view, I don't believe that you have to take care of manual cleanup, but when you use `on` (like my example), then it is required that you call "off" or event listeners will multiply.

Comment: Hmm. I definitely don't have a close method. Marionette 2.2.1, Backbone 1.1.0

Comment: Perhaps in older versions, the method used might be destroy for you, or empty. But there should be one available, otherwise regions wouldn't serve any purpose. Subview management is Marionette's thing.

Comment: Thanks for your patience Kim. I do have an empty() method. I created a new view, I show it in the region, and immediately run region.empty(). DOM elements are removed, but the View is still in memory.

Comment: For the close method, I'm sure that stopListening is called, which makes the view marked for garbage collection (because references to the DOM are also removed. I am not 100% certain if this is the case for empty(). I'm not sure why you just don't upgrade to a newer version of the library? Note that "marked for garbage collection" doesn't mean that the object will immediately be cleaned up. The garbage collector makes these decisions and it happens only periodically depending on your app.

Comment: Hey @KimGysen, what version of Marionette are you on, I can't find the `close` method. Did find a reference to it in what seems to be non-official docs, http://alchapone.github.io/marionette.doc/marionette/regions/region.html#basic-use, but it's not in my version of Mn (old, 2.0.0) nor the edge version (2.3.0). A telling sign, the docs there use `preventClose` today, Mn is using `preventDestroy`.

Comment: Yeah I've upgraded to 2.3.0 and don't have the close method. I'd love to know what version you're using @KimGysen. If I'm understanding you correctly, doing a heap snapshot can actually be unreliable since certain items may have been marked for garbage collection but still be listed?

Comment: Reading the docs (2.3.0), Regions seem to have the traditional show() method as well as an empty() method to "shut down" a view. Additionally, Regions have an optional preventDestroy parameter to keep their original view around when making the region show a different view, meaning a view is destroyed by default when having its region show a different view. I assume that this means that calling region.empty() should destroy the view that lives in that region completely, meaning removing it from memory as well. http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.region.html#showing-a-view

Comment: I was mistaken; I'm the one still using versoni 1. Check out this thread: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/1585 Empty calls destroyView. If you check your region in the console, you'll notice that the view has a pseudo-private method _destroyView.

Comment: Im marking this as the accepted answer because it is correct, however I was having a plethora of other issues that prevented the view from destroying, including some jquery code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's a bit late for me to comment to this. The only thing I can say is that the object is collected by the garbage collector when all references have been removed. This, in case of a bb view object, is usually a reference to the DOM (jQuery in case of bb) or a bb model that has been bound to the view. I hope that your issues were solved.